# Adding more parameters to AsynchTask doInBackground(Params... params)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to make a file operations class have its functions invoked in the background asynchronously. I want to be able to use the AsyncTask's doInBackground method to switch between file operations, however when adding an int parameter for use as a switch, I get an error.

```
class Files extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Boolean> {
    private static final int COPY   = 0;
    private static final int DELETE = 1;

    public boolean copy(String[] copyDir, String[] pasteDir) {
        return doInBackground(COPY, copyDir, pasteDir);
    }

    public boolean delete(String[] files) {
        return doInBackground(DELETE, files);
    }

    //Async operation handler
    protected Boolean doInBackground(int o, String[]...files) {
        Boolean task = false;
        try {
            //Operation switch
            switch (o) {
                case COPY:
                    task = copyFiles(files[0], files[1]);
                    break;
                case DELETE:
                    task = deleteFiles(files[0]);
                    break;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return task;
    }

    public boolean copyFiles(String[] inputPaths, String[] outputPaths) throws IOException {
        //Copy Logic
    }

    public boolean deleteFiles(String[] paths) throws IOException {
        //Delete Logic
    }
}
```

Is something similar to this implementation possible? If not, what is it about the abstract method that does not allow for something like this?

Comment: I think you can not pass two param in doInBackground method. read this doc. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html this will clear your concept.

Comment: this implementation is not possible. but you can achieve same by create an getter-setter class for holding more then one type of values and then send to `doInBackground` method as vargs argument

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Would I have to use an object array and pass it in as the varargs argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use multiple constructors / setter for passing in group of arguments you want to pass to and in **doInBackground** method act upon type of operation you have passed to AsyncTask by setter methods.